# How to implement a role base login in Nodejs and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Am developing a login system that has both admin and user, though i was able to develop the user login route which is working fine, and am also using the same method I use in developing the user login to develop the admin login, but am adding a restriction to it by checking if the user level in my MongoDB is not equal to a certain value that defines the user role

I have tried reading through some articles online (Medium), but their codes don't look like solving my issues

Here is my mongodb User schema.
Note: by default user role is 4 which means it only works on the user routes not on the admin routes

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  role:{
    type: Number,
    default : 4,
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Here is the login route

```
// @route   Post api/admins/login
// @desc    Login Admin / Returning JWT Token
// @access  Public
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);

  // Check Validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // Find user by email
  User.findOne({ email }).then(user => {
    // Check for Admin
    if (!user) {
      errors.email = 'User not found';
      return res.status(404).json(errors);
    }
    // Check to see if level meet admin role
    if(user.role = 4){
      errors.role = 'You are not allowed to view this page'
      return res.status(404).json(errors);
    }

    // Check Password
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        // User Matched
        const payload = { id: user.id, name: user.name, role: user.role  }; // Create JWT Payload

        // Sign Token
        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          { expiresIn: null },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: 'Bearer ' + token
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        errors.password = 'Password incorrect';
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I expect the user with any role with the number 4 should not be allowed to login into the admin routes. so this can serve as a restriction to all user that are not Admin because my admin level is from 1-3 and users are 4 alone

Comment: bro, you are using `if(user.role = 4)` which is always true, change it to `if(user.role == 4)`

Comment: ohh, i never notice that could be the problem, thank you....

Comment: haha, using = instead of == is a common mistake. i did this mistake couple of times too :) no problem, happy coding :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i did was to change the

```
if(user.role = 4)
```

**to**
 `if(user.role == 4)`

this solve the problem